# AIRFLOW: use .replace() or relativedelta() in jinja template for {{ds}}

Tags: python, macros, airflow

My goal is to return 1st day of previous month based on airflow macro variable {{ds}} and use it e.g. in HiveOperator.

E.g. For ds = 2020-05-09 I expect to return: 2020-04-01

The solution I found and tried were:

```
SET hivevar:LAST_MONTH='{{ (ds.replace(day=1) - macros.timedelta(days=1)).replace(day=1) }}';
SET hivevar:LAST_MONTH='{{ ds + macros.dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=-1, day=1) }}'
```

But both resulted in errors:

```
Error rendering template: replace() takes no keyword arguments 

Error rendering template: must be str, not relativedelta
```

and when rendered didn't show any dates.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you please share examples of expected output? do you mean that for 2020-05-09 you want to get 2020-05-01 ?

Comment: For 2020-05-09 I expect to receive: 2020-04-01

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
{{ (execution_date + macros.dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=-1, day=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") }}
```

Example:

```
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 4, 1),

}
with DAG(dag_id='stackoverflow',
         default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval=None,
         catchup=False
         ) as dag:
    run_this = BashOperator(
        task_id='example',
        bash_command='echo ds is {{ ds }} modified ds is {{ (execution_date + macros.dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=-1, day=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") }}',
    )
```

[image]

Comment: what is the difference between ds and execution_date variables? Because besides that var anme my example was the same anbd it's not working: `{ ds + macros.dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=-1, day=1) }}`

Comment: ds is string, executeion_date is Pendulum

Comment: How can I use this on string? I'm passing date as a runtime argument as a string

Answer (score 0):

According to [airflow doc](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html#variables) `{{ execution_date }}` is deprecated. So, you can keep using `{{ ds }}`, but you should convert it into datetime. Of course `{{ ds }}` depends on you cron time.

If you cron time is monthly, you could use only replace() function:

> `"{{ macros.datetime.strptime(ds, '%Y-%m-%d').replace(day=1) }}"`

If you cron time is daily, use replace() and then relativedelta():

> `"{{ (macros.datetime.strptime(ds, '%Y-%m-%d').replace(day=1) - macros.dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}`